# missing translation in react native expo i18n

Tags: reactjs, react-native, localization, translation, i18next

so in my app I need to have my text in Spanish and English depending on how it's config on the cellphone itself. Anyway, after a lot of research, every try that I did come up with the same conclusion that is [missing 'en.Messages' translation]. Can someone tell me what am I missing or doing wrong?

**APP.JS**

```
  import { loadLocale } from "./i18n";

  const init = async () => {
    await loadLocale();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  }, []);
```

**i18n.js**

```
import * as Localization from "expo-localization";
import i18n from "i18n-js";

i18n.defaultLocale = "en";
i18n.locale = "en";
i18n.fallbacks = true;

export const loadLocale = async () => {
  for (const locale of Localization.locales) {
    if (i18n.translations[locale.languageCode] !== null) {
      i18n.locale = locale.languageCode;
      switch (locale.languageCode) {
        case "en":
          import("./translations/en.json").then((en) => {
            i18n.translations = { en };
          });
          break;
        default:
        case "es":
          import("./translations/es.json").then((es) => {
            i18n.translations = { es };
          });
          break;
      }
      break;
    }
  }
};

export default i18n;
```

**translations folder**

```
inside the translations folder are 2 files call en.json / es.json
{
    "Messages": "Messages!",
}
```

**Messages.js**

```
import i18n from "../i18n";

<Text>{i18n.t("Messages")}</Text>
```

Comment: To whoever might get here searching for a solution, just make sure the i18n object is set up in the same scope that it is going to be used, was exporting a function, and had it outside that function

Answer (score 0):

Try setting defaultLocale before you load locale.

```
import { loadLocale } from "./i18n";

     i18n.defaultLocale = "en";
     i18n.locale = "en";
     i18n.fallbacks = true;

  const init = async () => {
    await loadLocale();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  }, []);
```

Comment: in app.js? i tried but it didnt change anything there

Comment: Can you please create an example on the sandbox, it will be easier to debug.

Comment: so now if i change in i18n.js file to i18n.defaultLocale = "es"; instead of "en" its working. so the issue it seems to be with the English translation

Comment: your Localization. locales is returning an empty array, here is the link I am able to reproduce and fix it. https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-zhukovsky-fwev7?file=/src/i18n.ts:334-354

Comment: https://whatdidilearn.info/2019/01/20/internationalization-in-react-native.html another link

Comment: thanks, I read it, the thing is that I shouldn't change the language manually but checking in which language is the device and changing automatically

Comment: Hey I fixed it! The article was really useful. Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: What was missing? ,Do a upvote to the link, so it will help others.